# GridView_RowDataBound (If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow)....include 2 IF's?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I've got a grid view which uses a "If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow" to calculate the total of a column and hold this in the footer.

```
  Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound

  If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
     Totalnumbers += Convert.ToInt16(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "RequestTotalnumbers"))
  ElseIf 
    e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Footer Then      
   e.Row.Cells(3).Text = String.Format("{0}", Totalnumbers)
    End If
```

However i now wish to also add....

```
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim datakey As String = GridView1.DataKeys(e.Row.RowIndex).Value.ToString()

    End If
```

so that it can transfer on click to another page....

```
    'Handle button click
    Protected Sub RowClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewCommandEventArgs) _
    Handles GridView1.RowCommand

    If e.CommandName = "Select" Then
        'Add to session variable; translate the index of clicked to Primary Key
        Session.Add("ID", GridView1.DataKeys(e.CommandArgument).Value.ToString)
        Response.Redirect(" ")
    End If
End Sub
```

I've tried combining to two if's together but have had no success...how can i do this?

Comment: I don't understand the question or problem. Which part is working and what part is not working?

Comment: They both work separably but not together. There part where the second if should read and then be able to redirect. on select nothing happens (and not because there is no response redirect in the code above)

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure, this may be what you want. Make sure you also added "datakeynames" property in your GridView.

```
'Handle button click
Protected Sub RowClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewCommandEventArgs) _
    Handles GridView1.RowCommand

    If e.CommandName = "Select" Then
       Dim row As GridViewRow = CType(CType(e.CommandSource, Control).NamingContainer, GridViewRow)
        'Add to session variable; translate the index of clicked to Primary Key
        Session.Add("ID", GridView1.DataKeys(row.RowIndex).Value.ToString)
        Response.Redirect(" ")
    End If
End Sub
```